# GnuPG encrypted copy of sent message

Tags: gnupg

How do I create an encrypted copy of a message, for my own records, before I send it to the recipient? That is, I want to send an encrypted message to Bob and I want a copy of this message, encrypted with my key that I don't send to Bob but keep for my records.

Does anyone have any code for this procedure?

Currently I'm using:

```
echo "message" | gpg --encrypt -a -r Bob
```

...which returns to stdout, from which I copy and paste over my previous unencrypted email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add yourself as recipient (being Alice), and both will be able to decrypt the message:

```
echo "message" | gpg --encrypt -a -r Bob -r Alice
```

There are GnuPG-Plugins for all relevant mail clients which make handling of encrypted mail easier and at the same time less error-prone.